# Bash: Why a file will be copied into the last directory when typed 'cp hey foo*'?

Tags: bash, command, cp

Structure as follows

> james/ 
>        hey /foo1 /foo2 /foo3

When typed this command

> cp hey foo*

I'm getting the following notification

> cp: omitting directory 'foo1' 
>   cp: omitting directory 'foo2'

And the file  **hey**  is copied into  **foo3**  directory.

Why is this happening so?
Why  **hey**  is been copied to  **foo3**  directory, why not to  **foo1**  and  **foo2** ?

Comment: What would you expect it to do? Put a copy of `hey` in each of the directory names starting with `foo`?

Comment: If that's what you want: `for d in foo*/; do cp -- hey "$d"; done`. Since there's only one destination argument per invocation of `cp` (check the man page!), you need one invocation per destination.

Comment: Yep, I want to copy **hey** into all -suffixed foo- directories. Thank you for your comment, I got my answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do this:

```
cp hey foo*
```

bash *expands* the arguments. In your case the command line expands to

```
cp hey foo1 foo2 foo3
```

Last argument is the target file/directory. `cp` refuses to copy directories unless `-R/-r` option is set, hence the messages.

And the `hey` file is copied in `foo3`

`cp` or any other command cannot tell the difference between a command line with `*` and a command line with the expanded args, unlike Windows cmd for instance.

If you succeed in passing the actual `*` char to `cp` (ex: `cp foo\* bar`) then `cp` will check for file called `foo*`. There's no wildcard mechanism expansion in commands (there are some in Windows ports but that's another story)

Note: this is not the way it should be used:

- If you *know* there's only directory with `foo` prefix, this could be a way to copy files in it without knowing the directory name precisely.
- more classical usage: `cp *.txt foo`

Note2: dangerous case: if you have `file1` and `file2` and you want to copy them in `foo`, and you type `cp file*`, omitting `foo` (or hitting RETURN by mistake), it will copy `file1` *over* `file2` (in shells that don't expand wildcards that could not happen).

In your case, if you want to copy `hey` to all `foo*` directories you have to make a loop:

```
for target in foo*
do
   cp hey "$target"
done
```

Comment: It's perhaps worth calling out (even though it's already implicit in your answer) that `cp` has no way of telling which expanded argument came from which part of the original command line, since it has no way of telling that any "original command line" even existed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have hinted that in my second note. You're right, I'll edit.

Comment: *nod*. As I read it, the OP wants to put a single copy of `hey` in each of the `foo*` directories, ie. to have all of them treated as destinations. You're covering why that doesn't work, but somewhat indirectly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Typical XY problem right? :) I have added the way to do it in the end of my answer. Finally it's better to try to be exhaustive to explain this classical problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: thanks for the edit! I did not test it obviously!